# Búsquedas de texto en Python

Tags: python

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño programa para buscar palabras o secuencias de palabras en una cadena de texto, y la función del programa sería devolver las posiciones donde se encuentran las letras. El código sería así:

```
def buscar_motivo(x,y):        
    indice = []
    for i,j in zip(x,y):            
       indice = x.find(y)
```

Pero el problema es que al detectar la primera secuencia de y que se encuentra en s, para y no busca más, aunque haya más secuencias. ¿Cuál es el problema? Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Puedes completar la pregunta con algunos datos de ejemplo, el resultado que esperas obtener y lo que estás obteniendo? Te pregunto porque veo que en tu intento usas la función `zip` por alguna razón

Comment: Pista: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres trabajar con texto y procesamiento de lenguaje natural, utiliza nltk, librería especializada para ello que seguro ya tienen las primitvas que deseas desarrollar.